# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name "setPassword" with signature

Tags: android, kotlin

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name "setPassword" with signature.
How come is it possible ?

[image: Without "private" it throws class formatError]

Comment: Where is the error? I don't see any error in the screen shot.

Comment: That's probably because data class generating getters and setters on it's own. I tried to make the password field private and it worked as expected. https://bit. ly/3DrdNHv (Shortened url because it's too lengthy)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a propert and a function in the format setPropertyname in kotlin-  kotlin automatically generates a function setPropertyname for you.  If you want to override the default behavior of that, use

```
var password: String
    set(value) {
        //do whatever
        //to set the property, use field=value
    }
```